# Error: Unable to resolve module `warnOnce` from ...../Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js

Tags: react-native

I am trying to communicate from react native to native by following [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-setup)

I am able to generate the library without any issues, but when I am referencing that in my code like

```
import MyLibrary from 'react-native-my-library'
```

I am getting the following error.

> error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `warnOnce` from `react-native-my-library/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js`: warnOnce could not be found within the project.

But, as [rickhanlonii](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24065) is suggesting I do have warnOnce file be in `./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Utilities/warnOnce.js` and I followed his instruction but cannot get this resolved.

I would really appreciate any help.

My package.json

```
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.3",
```